# What does the phrase "Critical edge" means?

Tags: idioms, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idiom-meaning

> But, amazingly,this practice provided the British with a critical edge in the Atlantic naval battle during 1941.

1. In this sentence what does "critical edge" means?
2. Then what will be the interpretation of the sentence above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Cambridge Dictionary:

> **Edge** noun (ADVANTAGE)
>   ​[ Singular ]. an advantage over other people:
>   *In terms of experience, she definitely had the edge over the other people that we interviewed.*

from the same source:

> **Critical** adjective (IMPORTANT).
>   of the greatest importance to the way things might happen:
>   *The president's support is critical (to this project).
>   a critical decision*

The text is suggesting that the "practice" gave the British Navy an important advantage in the battle.

Answer (score 0):

"Critical edge" here means "*considerable advantage*" (in the 1941 naval battle) over their enemy.

​[edge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/edge)

> - an advantage over other people:

[critical](http://B2%20of%20the%20greatest%20importance%20to%20the%20way%20things%20might%20happen:%20The%20president's%20support%20is%20critical%20(to%20this%20project).%20a%20critical%20de)

> - of the greatest importance to the way things might happen:
>     The president's support is critical (to this project).

(Cambridge Dictionary)